# Using Kendo UI Upload Widget within a Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, kendo-ui

I am trying to use the Kendo UI Upload widget within a lightbox window. After I choose a file, however, the file name is repeated four times below the Select button (it should only appear once of course).

I have tried using the Kendo Window widget and Fancybox as my lightbox libraries, but I get the same result with either of them.

I have also verified that the Upload widget works fine when I don't put it inside a lightbox. (But I really need it to work inside the lightbox!)

Anyone ever run into this before?

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/index.html

Thanks.

Comment: I never had this problem. Show some code (perhaps a www.jsfiddle.net) which reproduces this problem.

Comment: I've seen something similar in older versions of jQuery. Do you get the same behavior with 1.8.2?